# Error while installing jira_python

Tags: python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I execute the following command

pip install jira_python

as per the documentation here - http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I get an error -

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jira-python (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for jira-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out documentation in [pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira).

To install:

```
pip install jira
```

or

```
easy_install jira
```

Comment: I figured this as well, this is the right answer :)

Comment: I needed to run with superuser permission (ie sudo pip install jira)